# dojo dijit.form.timetextbox disabled but value still present

Tags: forms, date, dojo

I want to have my dojo `dijit.form.timetextbox` disabled but the last set value still displayed.

If I set the disabled attr to true the field is disabled but the value is gone. Is there any other way?

```
dijit.byId('form_endtime').set('disabled', true);
```

I am using Dojo 1.6

As I found this is only a problem on Chrome

Comment: Uhm, IIRC "disabled" doesn't mean "blank". It means "the user can't change this" plus "if this is in a plain HTML `<form>` the browser entirely skips this field when sending data to the server." If you don't mind "losing" the last-set value, you can probably do `.set("value","")` .

Comment: I just want the widget to be uinselectable (grayed out) but the value in stll displayed.

Comment: Does setting `readonly` instead of `disabled` get you what ou want?